# Error in updating google sheets using api (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-api

I'm using googleapis npm package to update google sheets. I'm running my nodejs appilcation in compute engine and trying to update the GSheet using the api but it is throwing an error:

> The API returned an error: Error: This operation is not supported for this document.

I am the owner of the sheet and i am able to update it manually but i'm getting the error when updating using the api.

Code:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

google.auth.getClient({
  keyFilename: 'keyFilename.json', //service account key json file
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
}).then(auth => {
  const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
  const data = {};
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
    spreadsheetId: 'mySpreadSheetId',
    range: 'Name of the sheet',
    valueInputOption: 'raw',
    resource: {
      values: data, //Data that i want to update to gsheet 
    }
  }, (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      reject(err);
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Could you include your code?

Comment: Tried your code but got this error: `TypeError: google.auth.getClient is not a constructor`.  Did you mean `google.auth.GoogleAuth` because that's the only way I could get past this part

Comment: Yes, as per the latest googleapi docs you need to use `const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth()` and then get auth client using `const authClient = await auth.getClient();`. For reference, please have a look at this document - https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/tasks/#api-reference

Answer (score 0):

In my case i uploaded a excel file to google drive and when i'm trying to update that sheet using api it did not allowed me to update. So,

> i created a new sheet in my drive and then i'm able to update it using the api.